# Proof of Poisson distribution for the "continuous time arrival model"

Tags: probability

To model the number of arrivals before time $t$, we divide $(0,t)$ into $n$ time slots of equal length $δ$, i.e. $=\frac{}{}$, and then assume the probability of having  arrivals in each interval are independent and obey the following

> $p\left( {k,\delta } \right) = o\left( {{\delta ^2}} \right) + \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
>   {1 - \lambda \delta }&{k = 0} \\ 
>   {\lambda \delta }&{k = 1} \\ 
>   0&{k > 1} 
> \end{array}} \right.$ ... (1)

From my lecture note, it says

> This assumption has following implications,
>
> 1. The probability of having one arrival in a small interval is proportional to its length by a constant ratio $λ$, which can be viewed as arrival rate.
> 2. As $δ→0$, the probability of have no arrivals in every small interval approaches 1.
> 3. As $δ→0$, the probability of getting two or more arrivals in the small interval decreases quadratically while the probability of getting one arrival in the small interval decreases linearly.

Let $\mathbb{P}\left( {k;\lambda ,t} \right)$ denote the probability of having $k$ arrivals before time $t$, then it shows the following equation that puzzles me.

> $\mathbb{P}\left( {k;\lambda ,t} \right) = \mathop {{\text{lim}}}\limits_{n \to \infty } \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
>   n \\ 
>   k 
> \end{array}} \right){\left( {\lambda \frac{t}{n}} \right)^k}{\left( {1 - \lambda \frac{t}{n}} \right)^{n - k}}$ ... (2)

I have no idea how to jump from above assumption (1) to probability (2), although intuitively it looks true. I googled and find [some other materials](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/81) use the same idea to derive Poisson distribution, but never show why (2) is true.

---

**My attempt**: let $n_i$ denote the number of slots that contain $i$ arrivals, then I think we have
$\mathbb{P}\left( {k;\lambda ,t} \right) = \mathop {{\text{lim}}}\limits_{n \to \infty } \mathop \sum \limits_{\mathop \sum \limits_{i = 1}^\infty  i{n_i} = k} {\left( {1 - \frac{{\lambda t}}{n} + o\left( {{\delta ^2}} \right)} \right)^{n - \mathop \sum \limits_{i = 1}^\infty  {n_i}}}{\left( {\frac{{\lambda t}}{n} + o\left( {{\delta ^2}} \right)} \right)^{{n_1}}}\mathop \prod \limits_{i = 2}^\infty  {\left( {o\left( {{\delta ^2}} \right)} \right)^{{n_i}}}$

This looks very complicated and I don't know how to go from this to (2).

---

PS: When (2) holds, we have the following limit,

> $\mathbb{P}\left( {k;\lambda ,t} \right) = \mathop {{\text{lim}}}\limits_{n \to \infty } \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
>   n \\ 
>   k 
> \end{array}} \right){\left( {\frac{{\lambda t}}{n}} \right)^k}{\left( {1 - \frac{{\lambda t}}{n}} \right)^{n - k}} = \frac{{{{\left( {\lambda t} \right)}^k}}}{{k!}}\mathop {{\text{lim}}}\limits_{n \to \infty } \frac{{n!}}{{\left( {n - k} \right)! \times {n^k}}}\mathop {{\text{lim}}}\limits_{n \to \infty } {\left( {1 - \frac{{\lambda t}}{n}} \right)^{n - k}} = \frac{{{{\left( {\lambda t} \right)}^k}}}{{k!}}{e^{ - \lambda t}}$

where $\mathop {{\text{lim}}}\limits_{n \to \infty } \frac{{n!}}{{\left( {n - k} \right)! \times {n^k}}} = 1$ and $\mathop {{\text{lim}}}\limits_{n \to \infty } {\left( {1 - \frac{{\lambda t}}{n}} \right)^{n - k}} = {e^{ - \lambda t}}$. This is the Poisson distribution when $t=1$.